# Get a value per row from a 2D numpy array based on column specified in another array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2D numpy array `A` and a 1D numpy array `col` with the same number of rows and values ranging the columns in `A`, how can I get a new 1D array that selects the corresponding column from each row in `A`?

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))
A
# array([[5, 0, 3],
#        [3, 7, 9],
#        [3, 5, 2],
#        [4, 7, 6],
#        [8, 8, 1]])
col = np.random.randint(A.shape[1], size=A.shape[0])
col
# array([2, 2, 0, 1, 1])
```

Based on `col`, I'd like to get element 2 from rows 0 and 1, element 0 from row 2, and 1 from rows 3 and 4: `[3, 9, 3, 7, 8]`.

The normal indexing doesn't work:

```
A[col]
# array([[3, 5, 2],
#        [3, 5, 2],
#        [5, 0, 3],
#        [3, 7, 9],
#        [3, 7, 9]])
A[:, col]
# array([[3, 3, 5, 0, 0],
#        [9, 9, 3, 7, 7],
#        [2, 2, 3, 5, 5],
#        [6, 6, 4, 7, 7],
#        [1, 1, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but is very slow for large arrays:

```
A[:, col].diagonal()
# array([3, 9, 3, 7, 8])
```